# Count(*) Query based on a time period by month need to add zero value instead of no data

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Database is Oracle 12C standard Edition.

I want to count certain values for a period of time by month. The query works but if a month has no data, I want to add zero instead of no data.

```
select  count(*) count_c,  to_char(close_date, 'YYYY-MM') yr_month 
from 
tbl
where  
close_date between add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -6) 
and 
trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - 1   
group by to_char(close_date, 'YYYY-MM') order by yr_month;

Result:
count_c   yr_month
353       2020-01
236       2020-02
266       2020-04
327       2020-05
369       2020-06
```

Note that there was no data for March, but I want the query to return March with zero as count.

```
Desired Output
count_c   yr_month
353       2020-01
236       2020-02
0         2020-03
266       2020-04
327       2020-05
369       2020-06
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need date generator and then left join you query to the generator.
For example:

```
select *
from 
   (
      select 
         add_months(
            date'2020-01-01' /* < start date */
           ,level - 1 /* number of months to add */
         ) dt
      from dual 
      connect by level<=months_between(
              date'2020-05-01' /* < end date */
             ,date'2020-01-01' /* < start date */
      )+1

   ) gen
   /* left join (
      {your_query here}
      ) data
   on gen.dt = data.dt
   */
```

Comment: You need to add +1 in connect by condition. Your currect query is excluding the last month

Comment: Thanks, fixed.   .

Comment: Great, thanks for the idea.